# ZFTool 2 – How to create an action?

Tags: zend-framework2, zftool2

I am using the ZFTool 2 to create modules and controllers in my projects. When I try to use it to create an action, I encounter an error.

In the documentation it says the following:

```
Action creation:
  zftool create action <name> <controllerName> <module> [<path>]    create an action in a controller                                                          

  <name>              The name of the action to be created                                                                                                                          
  <controllerName>    The name of the controller in which the action should be created                                                                                              
  <module>            The module containing the controller                                                                                                                          
  <path>              The root path of a ZF2 application where to create the action
```

So I entered the following into Terminal:

`zftool create action test Index Mymodule my-project-root`

I get the following (not that helpful) error message back:

`Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided`

I also tried it like this, with the same result:

`zftool create action testAction IndexController Mymodule my-project-root`

Am I doing something wrong here? Why is my action not created? What arguments are invalid?

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments I also tried to create the action after changing into the project root to make sure the path is not the problem. I got the following error message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (ZFTool) could not be initialized.' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/myProject/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:189`

Comment: have you tried to create the action inside the application directory ? just to know if the problem is in the path.

Comment: @blackbishop I just tried that, result is the following error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (ZFTool) could not be initialized.' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/myProject/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:189`.

Comment: sven, i just updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the last argument `my-project-root` is wrong. It should represent a correct physical root path of a ZF2 application.

Try this:

```
zftool create action foobar   Index        Application /path/to/your/project
                     [action] [Controller] [Module]    [Your project root]
```

**EDIT:**
After your updates, i realized that problem may related with your ZFTool installation. (Assuming that you're trying to use zftool as an external command). Try to attach it as module into your project:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/projectroot
$ php composer.phar selfupdate
$ php composer.phar require --dev zendframework/zftool:dev-master
$ ./vendor/bin/zf.php create action foobar Index Application
```

As you can see, there are no need to setting project root explicitly in this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help! To make sure the path is not a problem, I've now changed into my project root folder before executing the command, but without much luck. I've added the error message I get to my post.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I had the ZFTool simply globally installed in my PATH for easy access, I didn't knew I need to add it to the project.